# How to build project with sdl2 library with make?

Tags: c++, makefile, build, sdl-2

I am reading https://www.willusher.io/pages/sdl2/, I in the first chapter, I got this file tree:

```
Lessons
├── bin
├── include
│   ├── res_path.hpp
│   └── sdl_error.hpp
├── Lesson1
│   └── src
│       ├── hello_world.cpp
│       └── test.cpp
├── makefile
└── res
    └── Lesson1
        └── hello.bmp
```

Now from the `Lessons` directory, I would like to build the `test.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include "res_path.hpp"
#include "sdl_error.hpp"

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
        print_err("sdl_init");

    std::cout << "Resource path is: " << getResourcePath() << std::endl;

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

But I do not know, how to include the `sdl2` dependencies. Here the makefile looks like this:

```
#project variables
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -I include
VPATH = include $(wildcard Lesson[0-9]/src)

#SDL2 vairables
CFLAGS = $(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
LDFLAGS = $(shell sdl2-config --libs)


test: test.o
test.o: res_path.hpp sdl_error.hpp -lSDL2
```

When run with `make` command, the output is:

```
g++  -I include  -c -o test.o Lesson1/src/test.cpp
g++ -lSDL2  test.o   -o test
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `getResourcePath(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `SDL_GetBasePath'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `SDL_free'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `print_err(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x42f): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1
```

Now I see the makefile gets the source file `src/test.cpp` correctly, but the `sdl2` library were not properly loaded (and thus those many linker errors). But I tried to get them in `$(CFLAGS)` and `$(LDFLAGS)` in the makefile

Comment: This is a common gotcha: dependencies come *after* the object files that depend on it. put `-lSDL2` at the end of your recipe, not your rule.

Comment: But I have no recipe. I am 100% trusting on implicit rules make will generate for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-lSDL2` needs to come after `test.o` in the command.

According to the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), the implicit rule you're using looks like this:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

Meaning your linker flags have to go to `LDLIBS` rather than `LDFLAGS`.

---

Also this looks wrong: `test.o: res_path.hpp sdl_error.hpp -lSDL2`. Remove the `-lSDL2` part.

Comment: I have changed the the rule to this: 
`BINDIR = bin`
`%: %.o $(LDLIBS)`
 `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $^`

Comment: But the file will not go to `$(BINDIR)/test` (which is `bin/test`), but why? I used simple pattern rule for executables

Comment: @milanHrabos Why change the rule like that? The only change I suggested is renaming `LDFLAGS` to `LDLIBS` (and removing `-lSDL2`), you shouldn't need to do anything else. Does this work?

Comment: I changed the rule because I do not want to specify target name. I just want the make find the target based on the command line and compile it. It does it correctly when there is no recipe (that is, just simple `%: %.o`) - implicit rule. But I need to add recipe in order to `mv` the bianry to `bin` directory. How to do that? If I add recipe, the implicit rule won't be performed. But I want it, so how can I *add* recipe to implicit rule?

Comment: @milanHrabos One question per post please. Does the change I suggested work or not? If it does, please make a new post about the new problem you're having.